# Immutable actions with Javascript ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutability

Is it possible to perform immutable actions with a JS `Map`?
How would you `set` or `delete` an item without altering the original `Map`?

Comment: ES6 `Map` is mutable, you can't make them immutable.

Comment: @VipinKumar I will try :)

Comment: *"How would you set or delete an item without altering the original Map?"* The simplest way would be to implement your own wrapper and clone the map on every mutation. But that's not memory efficient. There are better approaches, such as *structural sharing*. You might want to look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the first part of question:

If you want to make your map immutable you can use Proxy to handle all getters/setters to the map, example is bellow:

**IMPORTANT:** This is slow and memory consuming way. Do not do this in real life. You was awared.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set(1, 'someValue');
const freezeThemAll = {
  get: (target, propName) => {
    if (propName === 'set') throw 'Sorry, map is immutable!';

    if (propName === 'get') {
      return target.get.bind(target);
    }

    return target[propName];
  }
};
const immutable = new Proxy(map, freezeThemAll);
try {
  console.log(`Trying to get some value: ${immutable.get(1)}`);
  console.log(`Trying to set some value: ${immutable.set(2, 'other value')}`);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

**But, if you really need this, try to search for related libs, like Mori or immutable.js**